# HttpListener Conflicts with existing registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a function (*ListenForJson*) in which I am using HttpListener to get requests and send responses from/to a specific address. I am calling this function inside *ActionResult Index()* so that it can run in the background. However, since I am calling it in the Homepage of my Webapp, whenever I click on the "Go to Home" button I receive an error the error

```
Failed to listen on prefix because it conficts with an existing registration on the machine
```

I understand the reason it happens but I do not know how I can stop it from happening.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => ListenForJson());
        thread.Start();
        return View();
    }

public void ListenForJson()
    {
        string[] prefixes = new string[] { "https://localhost:44337/" };
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            //Get Body(Json)
            System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
            System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            JsonObject = DeserializeJson(json);
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            var responseJson = JsonSerialization("SERVICE");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[] { };
            response.ContentType = "Application/json";
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseJson);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            context.Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are few problems with this approach. First, creating an inbound socket requires priviledges that could be missing in your app pool identity. Then, creating a socket on localhost makes it not reachable from other machines. Third, each consecutive call to your `Index` will try to spawn yet another listener on the same port (thus, complain about an existing registration).

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am currently using localhost because it's a test environment and I also know the reason the listener complains. However, I do not know how to approach it differently in order for the program to stop complaining.

Comment: Since you are already in a web app, what's the reason behind an extra http listener? Just have an additional endpoint in the app itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I could do that?

Comment: Well, you already have a web app. I conclude this from seeing `ActionResult Index` in your snippet and a `mvc` tag. Web apps are run on web servers and listen to incoming requests. An MVC web app can have multiple endpoints (= multiple actions and multiple controllers), each defined endpoint (e.g. `/home/index`) can be reached from outside. But for some reason, instead of exposing another endpoint (= another action in another controller) you create a `HttpListener` in your web app. It's either something important missing in your description or you don't exactly know what you're doing.